# setting variable value on click

Tags: javascript

Im new in programming and im trying to make my first project in js - hangman game (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game))

So basically i got two buttons in my HTML file, lets say its look like this:

```
<button id="movies">Movies</button>
<button id="animals">Animals</button>
```

i want this buttons to be responsible for changing categories in my game. In js i got:

```
var movies = ["Shawshank Redemption","Alice in a Wonderland"];
var animals = ["Blue whale","Raspberry Crazy-Ant"];

var choice = 1; 

if (choice === 0){
    var pwdDraw = Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length);
    var pwd = movies[pwdDraw];
    pwd = pwd.toUpperCase();
    document.write(pwd);
    }
else if (choice === 1){
    var pwdDraw = Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length);
    var pwd = animals[pwdDraw];
    pwd = pwd.toUpperCase();
    document.write(pwd);
}
```

and this is the place where im stucked, i dont know how change var choice by clicking button (also i want to reload page after click). Im at the beginning on my way with js, so i want this code to be pure js, not any customized library.

Comment: You don't want to mix javascript with html like that.... also I don't recommend using `document.wrtie()` If I were you I would either append new elements or update editing elements. Maybe a beginners tutorial on using javascript would be useful for you. It will help you understand how javascript works and how to run it with your application. Also shouldn't `animals.length` and `animals[pwdDraw];` be `filmy.length` and `filmy[pwdDraw];`  since `animals` doesn't exist but `filmy` does...

Comment: Okay I have decided to write you something that you might find useful as I assume you plan to add more buttons and array's. With what you currently have you will be forever in a if/elseif with repeating source code so here's something that will require very little to update. Only thing you will need to add is a button and the array, javascript will take care of the rest. https://jsfiddle.net/1py4c3py/ Details on how this works are explained in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button onclick="changeCategory(number)">Click me</button>
<script>
function changeCategory() {
    //[..]
}
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `onclick` event. After some changes your code should look like this.

```js
var movies = ["Shawshank Redemption", "Alice in a Wonderland"];
var animals = ["Blue whale", "Raspberry Crazy-Ant"];

var catname = document.getElementById('cat-name');

function selectCategory(choice) {
  var pwd, pwdDraw;
  if (choice === 0) {
    pwdDraw = Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length);
    pwd = movies[pwdDraw];
  } else if (choice === 1) {
    pwdDraw = Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length);
    pwd = animals[pwdDraw];
  }
  pwd = pwd.toUpperCase();
  catname.innerText = pwd;
}
```

```html
<p>Choose Category</p>
<button id="movies" onclick="selectCategory(0)">Movies</button>
<button id="animals" onclick="selectCategory(1)">Animals</button>

<div id="cat-name"></div>
```

## Even better with Object and Arrays

```js
var categories = {
  movies: ["Shawshank Redemption", "Alice in a Wonderland"],
  animals: ["Blue whale", "Raspberry Crazy-Ant"]
};

var catname = document.getElementById('cat-name');

function selectCategory(choice) {
  var pwdDraw = Math.floor(Math.random() * categories[choice].length);
  var pwd = categories[choice][pwdDraw];
  pwd = pwd.toUpperCase();
  catname.innerText = pwd;
}
```

```html
<p>Choose Category</p>
<button id="movies" onclick="selectCategory('movies')">Movies</button>
<button id="animals" onclick="selectCategory('animals')">Animals</button>

<div id="cat-name"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain me why this code is only working here in 'run code snippet'? when im copying exactly the same code into for example bracktes it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't put those `<br>` in JS code like that.
If you want to try to get the choice by clicking on the button then here's how you can do it:

**HTML**

```html
<button id="movies" class="choice" value="0">Movies</button>
<br/>
<button id="animals" class="choice" value="1">Animals</button>
```

**JS**

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");

function doSomething(e)
{
    // You can get choice value by either doing:
    var choice = e.target.value;
    // OR
    var choice = this.value;
    
    // Continue your work here
}

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", doSomething);
}
```

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks a lot for feedback, but i still have some troubles of implementing this js changes, When im doing it on new file with only  category changer everything is running smooth. But when i try to add this to my existing code its doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for feedback, but i still have some troubles of implementing this js changes, When im doing it on new file with only  category changer everything is running smooth. But when i try to add this to my existing code its doesnt work at all. Here you got my code:

codepen.io/iSanox/project/editor/DGpRrY/